# Android table creation Failure (near "autoincrement": syntax error)?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
 public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
 public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
 public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE2 = "MY_TABLE2";
 public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_ID2 = "_id2";
 public static final String KEY_CONTENT1 = "Content1";
 public static final String KEY_CONTENT2 = "Content2";
 public static final String KEY_CONTENT3 = "Content3";

 //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
                                                        +KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                                                        + KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null);";

 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE2 = "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" 
                                                        + KEY_ID2 + " integer autoincrement, " 
                                                        + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null, " 
                                                        + KEY_CONTENT3 + " text not null, "
                                                        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_ID2+") REFERENCES "+MYDATABASE_TABLE+" ("+KEY_ID+"));";
```

I can not find out what gives the following error, please help me out thank you.

> 09-29 13:41:19.760: ERROR/Database(334): Failure 1 (near
>   "autoincrement": syntax error) on 0x218df0 when preparing 'create
>   table MY_TABLE2 (_id2 integer autoincrement, Content2 text not null,
>   Content3 text not null,  FOREIGN KEY (_id2) REFERENCES MY_TABLE
>   (_id));'.
>
> 09-29 13:41:19.770: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(334): Shutting down VM
>
> 09-29 13:41:19.770: WARN/dalvikvm(334): threadid=1: thread exiting
>   with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>
> 09-29 13:41:19.791: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 09-29 13:41:19.791: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{sep.com/sep.com.SepActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "autoincrement": syntax
>   error: create table MY_TABLE2 (_id2 integer autoincrement, Content2
>   text not null, Content3 text not null,  FOREIGN KEY (_id2) REFERENCES
>   MY_TABLE (_id));

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In short: `In SQLite a column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement.` There is no `autoincrement` keyword in SQLite, that is why you are getting an error.

You can find out more on [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1).

**EDIT:** just writing `integer primary key` it is enough. `SQLite` will automatically increment your `ids`.

**EDIT2:** Your `onUpgrade()` method should look like this :

```
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            Log.w("MyAppTag","Updating database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + " .Existing data will be lost.");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MY_TABLE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MY_TABLE2);
            onCreate(db);
        }
```

Comment: thank you, but how can i add autoincrement to the  code. im really new to android programming please be kind enf to tell me what i should do to the code.

Comment: **i did what you have said and then i got this following error**

 09-29 14:16:58.580: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sep.com/sep.com.SepActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Content2: , while compiling: SELECT _id, Content1, Content2, Content3 FROM MY_TABLE

Comment: I think you need to upgrade your database. increase the version and be sure that you properly implement onUpdate()

Comment: Hi again, 
well how to do so... always when i do changers it wont get updated..

 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

**this is only in my upgrade() func.**

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
+ KEY_ID2 + " integer autoincrement, "
```

should be this:

```
+ KEY_ID2 + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
```

If you follow the syntax diagrams for [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) you'll see that `autoincrement` should only come after `primary key`.

[image]
[image]

If you want `_id2` to be a foreign key then you don't want it to be auto increment at all though.

Comment: i did what you have said and then i got this following error


09-29 14:16:58.580: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sep.com/sep.com.SepActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Content2: , while compiling: SELECT _id, Content1, Content2, Content3 FROM MY_TABLE

Comment: @LoshWick: The `Content2` column is in `MY_TABLE2` not `MY_TABLE`.

Comment: private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("             +KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
               + KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null);";

 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE2 = "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE2 + " ("           + KEY_ID2 + " integer primary key autoincrement, "              + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null, "                + KEY_CONTENT3 + " text not null, "
               + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_ID2+") REFERENCES "+MYDATABASE_TABLE+" ("+KEY_ID+"));";
what have i done wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

An above answer says that 'There is no autoincrement keyword in SQLite.' This is incorrect. There is a keyword called 'autoincrement' and I used it in the primary key.

For example:

```
   static final String CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE="CREATE TABLE Location"+
            "( LocationID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            " RestuarantID int not null," +
            " Latitude float not null," +
            " Longitude float not null)";
```

Also make sure when you enter data to this table use the keyword 'null' in the place of the primary key.

Like this:

```
   static final String INSERT_LOCATION= "Insert into Location values" +
            "(null,1002,6.905369,79.851514)";
```

Answer (score 2):

Three things:

- Remove the trailing ; from the statements.
- Add "primary key" constraint to the autoincrement column
- Remove autoincrement from PK columns - it will happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE app (a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, B VARCHAR);
sqlite> insert into app (b) values ('');
sqlite> insert into app (b) values ('a');
sqlite> 
sqlite> insert into app (b) values ('b');
sqlite> insert into app (b) values ('c');
sqlite> insert into app (b) values ('d');
sqlite> select * from app;
1|
2|a
3|b
4|c
5|d
sqlite> exit;
```

**NOTE:** IN SQLite there in no `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword. So, you have to just use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL`. It will automatically insert the incremented value for the attribute.