# SQLite syntax error near "CREATE TABLE"

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax-error

Here's my code:

```
    String CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("  + 
            KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            "title TEXT, "+
            "author TEXT, "+
            "state TEXT);";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE);
```

The LogCat says :  12-11 23:43:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(3706): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE TABLE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE PapersTable(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, author TEXT, state TEXT);

Answer (score 4):

The `CREATE TABLE` syntax is all right as you've posted it.

I suspect there's a non-breaking space (ASCII 0xA0) between `CREATE` and `TABLE`. Replace it with the regular space (ASCII 0x20). That would explain the syntax error you posted: parser is treating `CREATE TABLE` as a single unknown token and not as two separate known tokens `CREATE` and `TABLE`.

What is definitely wrong is that you call `db.close()` on the `SQLiteDatabase db` passed in as a parameter to your function. You should only close databases you opened yourself and closing it this way will lead to an exception, albeit a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your onCreate method.

1. Remove AUTOINCREMENT for KEY_ID as it is already declared as Primary KEY.
2. Remove ";" you placed just after the last bracket in string i.e. second last semicolon in string CREATE_DATABASE.
3. Remove db.close() from oncreate()

**Code To Replace:**
String CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+ " ( "+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_TITLE+"TEXT, "+KEY_AUTHOR+"TEXT, "+KEY_STATE+"TEXT )";
db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE);

Comment: Removing AUTOINCREMENT would change the semantics, and a semicolon at the end of an SQL statement, while being superfluous, works just fine.

Comment: There is no need of AUTOINCREMENT in primary key attribute as this property is already acquired by the PRIMARY KEY.
Semicolon at the end of create table bracket is not a correct way to create a table so plz remove that.
db.close() is also not required in onCreate() as it is required when we perform some operations on database tables so you can remove that too.

Comment: Without AUTOINCREMENT, the IDs of deleted records might be reused. (Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)!) There is nothing incorrect about the semicolon (and in any case this has nothing to do with the problem in the question).

Comment: yeah I agree but there is no problem if a record uses deleted id again.It will be a new entry with old id so user can access data easily. and yeah there is nothing incorrect about semicolon but it is useless , there is no need of that semicolon so one can omit that.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was missing the closing `)` after the table body.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST user_table (
  id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  title TEXT,
  author TEXT,
  state TEXT
); -- this closing ')' was missing
```

Answer (score -1):

In SQLite, a column declared integer primary key will auto increment, so try removing that:

```
String CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("  + 
        KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
        "title TEXT, "+
        "author TEXT, "+
        "state TEXT);";
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594541/android-table-creation-failure-near-autoincrement-syntax-error) for reference.

Comment: The linked answer is wrong. SQLite supports `AUTOINCREMENT` and the semantics of `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` are slightly different. See http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html