# Create table sqlite syntax error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "case":
>   syntax error (code 1):, while compiling

**At**

```
CREATE TABLE case ( case_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, case_body TEXT, case_title TEXT, case_published INTEGER, case_thumbnil TEXT,case_type TEXT );
```

Can any one please tell me what is the problem, I am testing this on Android 5.0.2

I have checked

[Android - SQLite - syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553760/android-sqlite-syntax-error-code-1-while-compiling-create-table)

and  this

[SQLite syntax error near "CREATE TABLE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532339/sqlite-syntax-error-near-create-table)

But could not get answer

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you cannot use reserved keywords to name table.

For more info see  [SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

So you may Change

```
CREATE TABLE case
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE caseTable
```

Answer (score 4):

Is it because `CASE` is a reserved SQL keyword? Try `CREATE TABLE [case]`